# mysql foreign key declaration confusion

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE members(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR(50),
    password char(128),
    salt char(128),
    status VARCHAR(20),
    profile VARCHAR(15),
    unlock_code INT,
    username VARCHAR(20),
    privilege VARCHAR(15)
);

CREATE TABLE member_details(
    detail_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    middle_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    contact VARCHAR(12),
    dob VARCHAR(10),
    nic VARCHAR(15),
    mobile VARCHAR(12),
    userid INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES members(id)
);
```

How the thing is that when I `DESCRIBE TABLE` it shows `MUL`.

Engine is InnoDB.

Also, is it okay to not declare foreign keys and just use JOINS in query and make it act like foreign key?

Comment: `If Key is MUL, the column is the first column of a nonunique index in which multiple occurrences of a given value are permitted within the column.`. See  [14.7.5.5 SHOW COLUMNS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html).

Comment: So, does it mean that this is a wrong approach? Does Mysql show any sign or keyword that indicates it is a foreign key?

Comment: Whether or not it's the wrong approach will depend on what you need. With the information you provide, it does not seem like the wrong approach. DESCRIBE TABLE will not give information whether or not it is a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the database without constraints! Make the columns 'act' like foreign keys but don't but constraints.

Make sure you have sufficient verification in server side scripting to handle those constraints there.